# In android, is it possible to get the current video detail like video title /videoid or videourl in my app when the youtube app is playing video? how?

Tags: android

I want to create an app which will listen youtube android app's current video playing. I want to access current video details like video title, video id or video url.

Comment: have you tried using `MediaMetadataRetriever` ?

Comment: youtube api is there, use `json` to get data

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever require url of the video. my requirement is to pick the url of that youtube app which is currently playing.

Comment: @user3627388 Have you got any solution ?